# What does "this" mean exactly in this code example?

Tags: javascript

As I understood "this" in Javascript should mean an object calling it, is that correct? What is "this" will mean in this example code below?
    `

```
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    myFunction(this);
}
};
xhttp.open("GET", "books.xml", true);
xhttp.send();

function myFunction(xml) {
var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>`
```

Comment: value of `this` depends on the execution context where you are using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here `this` means `XMLHttpRequest` object which is `xhttp` here . But the value of  `this` can be different based on the context . In a global execution context outside of any function `this` points to the `window` object in javascript.

Check this link for more reference :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this